# Value not mapping correctly on Y axis using GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, yaxis

I am new to R and have very simple code.  I am trying to create a barchart with 2 variables and 6 observations; however, the data appears to be plotting incorrectly.  The combined value for MAYBE is 5.9, the combined value for NO is 5.3 and the combined value for YES is 5.3  Categories MAYBE and NO appear to be showing correctly; however, YES appears to be showing 3.2 and not 5.3. Can you please review and advise what might be wrong with my code.

```
library(tidyverse)

xaxis_data <- c("YES","NO","MAYBE")

yaxis_data <- c(2.1,1.6,3.4,3.2,3.7,2.5)

data_to_plot <- data.frame(cbind(xaxis_data,yaxis_data),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(data=data_to_plot) +
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x = xaxis_data,y=yaxis_data,fill = xaxis_data),stat="identity")[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `cbind` converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class.  The `xaxis_data` is `character` class and it converts the whole matrix to `character`.  Instead, we can just construct with `data.frame` alone.

```
data_to_plot <- data.frame(xaxis_data,yaxis_data,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data_to_plot)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ xaxis_data: chr  "YES" "NO" "MAYBE" "YES" ...
#$ yaxis_data: num  2.1 1.6 3.4 3.2 3.7 2.5
```

If we use the `cbind` with `data.frame`

```
str(data.frame(cbind(xaxis_data,yaxis_data),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ xaxis_data: chr  "YES" "NO" "MAYBE" "YES" ...
#$ yaxis_data: chr  "2.1" "1.6" "3.4" "3.2" ... ### character class
```

Using the OP's code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data_to_plot) + 
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x = xaxis_data,y=yaxis_data, 
         fill = xaxis_data),  stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the detailed answer.  I really appreciate it!